# Cannot get PostgreSQL ODBC to work in Connection String

Tags: postgresql, unicode, connection, odbc

I am having an issue and just can't seem to resolve it.  I cannot get my postgresql connection string to work.  Everything works fine with I create a DSN, but when I try to utilize the driver in a connection string I keep getting the datasource not found error.  I have PostgreSQL ANSI(x64),PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(ANSI),PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE),PostgreSQL Unicode(x64).  In the connection string I use the Unicode one.  Again, in the DSN and ODBC Manager it works great.  But I am using classic ASP (in IIS7) to pull data from the dB and I keep getting error. People were referring me to the connection string site, and I've tried everything I can think of.  To me, it looks perfect, but just can't get past that error.  Here is the string that I am using:

```
cst = "Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};Server=ipaddress;Port=5432;Database=dbname;Uid=uid;Pwd=pw;"
```

Please please help?

By the way, I'm new to this site, so if I do something wrong with this question, please let me know.  Thanks so much.

Comment: *I keep getting error*. **What is the *exact text* of the error message?**

Comment: Here's the exact text of the datasource not found error:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005'

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: I know I don't have a default driver specified but don't know why it wont take my driver in connection string?  Maybe do I need to install different versions.  I have x64 because that it what my server is

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know classic ASP has a 32-bit server executable.

That means you need the 32-bit ODBC driver, not the 64-bit one, as *the driver must match the client architecture* not that of the PostgreSQL server.

Install and select the 32 bit PostgreSQL ODBC driver.

Comment: Aah,  thanks so much.  Do you know if there are any instruction sites or something?  I installed from http://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/msi/psqlodbc_09_03_0300.zip and now Im getting "Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 5: Access is denied" when loading asp page. Went into manager %SystemRoot%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe, but when try to add new DSN, getting "The setup routines for the PostgreSQL Unicode ODBC Driver could not be loaded due to a system error code 126: The specified module could not be found.  (C:\Program Files(.86)\psqoODBC\0903\bil\psqlodbc35W.dll)"

Comment: That I'm afraid is beyond my ODBC-fu. Suggest posting a separate new question and linking back to this for context.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same exact problem. Here is how I got it working with classic ASP under IIS7:

- Install Visual C++ 2010 X64:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

- Install PSQLODBC X64

http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/

- Run windows ODBC Administrator (search for odbc in windows search)
- In System DSN tab, create a connection to the Database and use the connection name in place of the connection string on the Classic ASP script

Update:

I was also able to get classic ASP to connect to PostgreSQL through a connection string:

`DBConn.Open "DRIVER={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=server_ip;Port=5432;DATABASE=database_name;UID=database_username;PWD=user_password;`